# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent belongsToMany three tables with one mappingtable possible resctrictions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mapping, database-relations

I have a little problem with Eloquent in Laravel 4.2... first of all sorry for the tables naming.

There are three tables:

- Users -Id -Identification -Name -Username ...
- SecurityAreas -Id -Identification -Description...
- SecurityAccessRights -Id -Identification ...
  Contains just two data sets "read" and "write"

these tables have got a mapping table:

- SecurityMapping -Id -SecurityAccessAreasId -SecurityAccessRightsId -UsersId

Now I am trying to display all Users with the specific "Area" and the belonging "AccessRights". Therefore I've specified my models like this:

```
User.php

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterace, RemindableInterface {
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;


    protected $table = 'Users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function securityAreas() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('SecurityAreas', 'SecurityMappings', 'UsersId', 'SecurityAreasId' );
    }

    public function securityAccessRights() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('SecurityAccessRights', 'SecurityMappings', 'UsersId', 'SecurityAccessRightsId' , 'SecurityAreasId' );
    }
}
```

And in my UserController.php I am trying to get the User.

```
$oUsers = User::with('securityAreas')->with('securityAccessRights')->get();
```

Now Eloquent loads all Information on the Userobject... in my View I want to display the Username the Areas and the belonging Rights.
Because the belonging between the "Areas" and the "AccessRights" I get the same Area two times... but I want to display it just once for each user with the bunched rights.
For Example: 
[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AD0e.png)

So my question is how can I select the "User" with his belonging unique Areas with the belonging "AccessRights"? Is there any function or possibility to sort the result at the controller? Or is there something with my Usermodel wrong and can I restrict the in any possible way?

I am a little bit confused...

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a multidimensional array

```
UserController.php

$oUsers = User::with('securityAreas')->with('securityAccessRights')->get();
foreach($oUsers as $oUser) {
  $arrUser = array();

  $arrUser['id'] = $oUser->Id;
  $arrUser['Name'] = $oUser->Name; 
  $arrUser['EMail'] = $oUser->EMail;
  $arrUser['ADUser'] = $oUser->Username;
  $arrUser['UserIdent'] = $oUser->Identification;
  $arrUser['SecurityAreas'] = array();

  $iCount = 0;

  foreach($oUser->securityAreas as $oArea) {
      if(!array_key_exists($oArea->Identification, $arrUser['SecurityAreas'])) {
          $arrUser['SecurityAreas'][$oArea->Identification] = array();
      }
      $arrUser['SecurityAreas'][$oArea->Identification][] = $oUser->securityAccessRights[$iCount]->Identification;

      $iCount++;
  }

  $arrReturn[] = $arrUser;
}
```

Example Output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                      [Name] => User, My 
                      [EMail] => 
                      [Username] => MyUser 
                      [UserIdent] => 000000
                      [SecurityAreas] => Array ( 
                                                [Area1] => Array ( 
                                                                  [0] => read
                                                                  [1] => write ) 
                                                [Area2] => Array ( 
                                                                  [0] => read ) 
                                                ) 
                       ) 
)
```

With this I can use different foreach-loops in my view to Output the values in their right scope for each User - Area - Right.

I thought my Relations in my Models aren't correct and there is a better way to get these results.

I hope this helps you also.

Anyway if anyone knows a better or another way I would appreciate to know it.